# JQuery slideUp not quite working; assign slide length by pixels?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On the bottom of a page, I have a fixed position div element. Below this is another div, but hidden (it's outside of the page margins). I'm trying to slide both divs up so the bottom one is visible (comes out of margin), but the JQuery is kind of confusing, slideUp makes it go down and I can't determine slide length by pixels?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#butt').click(function() {
    $('#messbar').slideUp();
    $('#botbar').slideUp();
  });
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#messbar').slideDown();
    $('#botbar').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
}
#botbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#messbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="butt">Slide</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <div id="botbar">
    text
  </div>
  <div id="messbar">
    more text
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've got so far. Below is how it should look when "slide" is clicked:

```css
    #container {
      height: 600px;
    }
    #botbar {
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      height: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #messbar {
      position: fixed;
      margin: auto;
      height: 20px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="botbar">
    text
  </div>
  <div id="messbar">
    more text
  </div>
</div>
```

And when reset, it should appear as the initial position the first snippet is in.

What I'm looking for is on "slide" click, `#botbar` and `#messbar` both slide up 20px, and on "reset" click, both slide back down 20px.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#butt').click(function() {
    $('#messbar').animate({bottom:0});
    $('#botbar').animate({bottom:$('#messbar').height()});
  });
  $('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#messbar').animate({bottom:-($('#messbar').height())});
    $('#botbar').animate({bottom:0});
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
}
#botbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#messbar {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="butt">Slide</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <div id="botbar">
    text
  </div>
  <div id="messbar">
    more text
  </div>
</div>
```